# C# MVC Object Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I am trying to use a JWT Encode function from the github link below.  This JWT is used by Google Wallet and the last section of the token is an object.  Can someone help me with the correct syntax for the "request" section.  I am getting a syntax error in the visual studio editor.

```
         public static string CreateJWT(int JobID)
   {
       var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>() {

            { "iss", "17114776323338359428" },
            { "aud", "Google" },
            { "typ", "google/payments/inapp/item/v1" },
            { "exp", "1309988959" },
            { "iat", "1409988959" },
            { "request", 
                  "name", "Piece of Cake",
                  "description", "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy",
                  "price", "10.50",
                  "currencyCode", "USD",
                  "sellerData", "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j" 
            }

        };

        var secretKey = "s_F084...";
        string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, secretKey, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
        return token;
   }
```

Comment: here is the JWT library I'm using: https://github.com/johnsheehan/jwt

Comment: Might help if you told us what Visual Studio was complaining about..

Comment: Visual Studio puts a blue line under the { before the "request" text.  The hover error code complains about 'No overload...' But I don't think the error msg is accurate really, I don't the github code is meant to work with an object inside the payload definition.  There seems to be no JWT encoding sample for C# / Google Wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is it.. but I'll give it a crack.

You have `Dictionary<string, object>`.. yet here:

```
{ "request", // missing "object" part..
    { "name", "Piece of Cake" },
    { "description", "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy" },
    { "price", "10.50" },
    { "currencyCode", "USD" },
    { "sellerData", "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j" } 
}
```

Perhaps try changing it to this:

```
{ "request", new Dictionary<string, object>() { // another dictionary.
        { "name", "Piece of Cake" },
        { "description", "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy" },
        { "price", "10.50" },
        { "currencyCode", "USD" },
        { "sellerData", "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j" } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not a valid way to initialize a `KeyValuePair<string, object>`:

```
        { "request", 
              "name", "Piece of Cake",
              "description", "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy",
              "price", "10.50",
              "currencyCode", "USD",
              "sellerData", "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j" 
        }
```

Did you mean something dynamic like

```
        { "request", new {
              name = "Piece of Cake",
              description = "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy",
              price = "10.50",
              currencyCode = "USD",
              sellerData = "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j" 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the JWT code from github is not meant to handle an object inside the payload?  Google is looking for a 'request' object as the last parameter for their JWT.